# Set boot option to hotkey in GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I want to set GRUB to boot up a particular option (eg, A different kernel version, different OS) when a certain key is pressed (eg, W to boot up windows with Ubuntu as default and L for Lubuntu). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. Is creating an extra line in the boot menu an option? In that case you select a different line in the boot menu instead of pressing W or L as proposed. But I guess you already have the two lines in the menu.

There is an option to automatically select the last choice you made.

Comment: That would work, of course, I was just hoping I could avoid it so I didn't need to open up the grub menu every time. Is there an alternate bootloader that can do this? syslinux maybe?

Comment: There is a way to make the GRUB menu appear automatically every time you boot. Then a timeout counts down, if you don't touch the keyboard it boots the default; if you touch the keyboard you can select another option.

Comment: Thanks, thought of the setting it to open menu automatically, but didn't remember the countdown, so that should work. Thanks!